# What is the equivalent of KeyValuePair in Swift 3

Tags: swift3

Here the C# code.

// Shows a List of KeyValuePairs.

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Cat", 1));
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Dog", 2));
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Rabbit", 4));

foreach (var element in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

What will be the equivalent in swift 3 for the above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KeyValuePair`is a dictionary, the Swift version is a bit shorter:

```
var list = [[String:Int]]()

list.append(["Cat": 1])
list.append(["Dog": 2])
list.append(["Rabbit": 4])

list.forEach{ element in print(element) }
```

Comment: [[String:Int]]() means array of Dictionary type. I notice there is a comma(,) in this ("Cat", 1) and your is "Cat" : 1 with (:) ,will this cause any problem or differences?

Comment: It's an array of dictionaries according to `List<KeyValuePair`. The syntax of a Swift literal dictionary is `"[Key:Value]"`. C# != Swift

Comment: you mean List<KeyValuePair > is not the same as [[String:int]] in term of Syntax, BUT what about the data? I need to use this for generate something for https commnication with certificate and sign certificate which base on c#. now need to use swift3. What I can do?